# Receiving "Rate Limit Exceeded" while writing into a Fusion Table

Tags: java, google-api, google-fusion-tables, google-api-java-client

I'm developing an web application that writes data to Fusion Tables using the API and a Service Account (OAuth2).

For some reason, after 30 INSERT's, I get "Rate Limit Exceeded" (403). The only workaround is to apply exponential backoff as in https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors.

According to the release notes (https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/release_notes), every INSERT counts for 5 requests, and my 30 INSERT's complete in ~1,5 minute, so this is about 5*30/90, thus less than 2 requests/user/second. Even if I have changed the limit in the API console to be 10, 50, 100 (requests/user/second), nothing changes; 30 INSERTS look like the best I can do in a row.

It seems that I'm exceeding some other limit, but which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit for write-requests is 30 per minute, see: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#quota

When you request more quota via the console (and get it) this will affect the number of API requests per day, but not the number of allowed write-requests per minute(I can't tell you if it's possible increase this limit)