# How to insert 1000s of records into a fusion table dynamically using Javascript

Tags: jquery, google-fusion-tables

I can insert fusion table data dynamically using below JavaScript code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Authorization Request</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function auth() {
            var config = {
                'client_id': '607567025394-rmte05500pvsoj12dsrie1cbei5te506.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables',
                'immediate': false
            };
            gapi.auth.authorize(config, function () {
                console.log('login complete');
                console.log(gapi.auth.getToken());
            });
        }
        function insert_row() {
            gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyAnEhw4Y7n5V7bN226wWo0tHs0Bd7jAzxA');

            gapi.client.load('fusiontables', 'v1', function () {                
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
                    var query = "INSERT INTO 1v228snvOypXSvzbtgZP_nhe_GcmBROV5G7lA0T0P(col0,col1,col2) VALUES ('a','a', 'a')"; 
                    gapi.client.fusiontables.query.sql({ sql: query }).execute(function (response) { console.log(response); });
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<button onclick="auth();">Authorize</button>
<br />
<button onclick="insert_row();">Insert Data</button>
<br />
<button onclick="showMap();">Show Map</button>
<br />
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Using the above code I tried to insert 50 records at a time into a fusion table, but it inserts only 30 rows. I tried many ways but I can't add more than 30. How can I insert 100's or 1000's of rows to the fusion table using the above code or any other code?

Comment: i think this is a restriction by google's api

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replay. If any other way to fix this issues.

Comment: I've updated your question to be a bit more grammatically correct, moved the Fusion Tables tag from the title to the tags. I also removed the C#, .net, and HTML tags from the question, as they did not appear to be used in the question.

Comment: Also, you may want to look into the [`import` command](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/using#ImportingRowsIntoTables) as I believe that is what you want, but this API is not my area of expertise.

Comment: ok thanks for your information Mike

Comment: Hi, Anybody know well how to import Excel sheet via .net, c# or javascript please share with exact code. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Fusion Tables **v1** used to have a quota restricting request rate 2 sec/request.
I was trying to look up this info, but couldn't find it anymore on Google's docs. 
See SO question [Receiving "Rate Limit Exceeded" while writing into a Fusion Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25892318/receiving-rate-limit-exceeded-while-writing-into-a-fusion-table)

You have probably hit some legacy function which still applies this quota.
I advise you to give it a try with [v2](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/reference/)

Comment: thanks for your replay. I tried to use gapi.client.load('fusiontables', 'v1', function () { }   to gapi.client.load('fusiontables', 'v2', function () {} but that time also i am getting below error on browser console.                              POST 403 (Forbidden) & tried to fusion table that time i can't insert more than 30 rows

Comment: i think you have to use oAuth2 for v2

Comment: How to use oAuth2 for v2. Please share with sample codes. If anyone shared sample codes it's very use full for me. thanks!!!!!